# PhpStorm git error

Tags: git, phpstorm

I've recently installed PhpStorm, I've tried to install Git but I keep getting the following error :

> Errors while executing git --version. exitCode=-1073741515 error

I can imagine the the Git path is probably wrong, although the file are at that location.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Download yourself Git, install and use it: https://git-scm.com/downloads/

Comment: Thanks!!! working great!!! i'm new here - how can i close this discussion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Sorry mate - just can't figure it out how to mark as answered .